# TeamCity: add a build to the build queue more than once

Tags: teamcity

Let's say I have 3 builds: B1, B2, B3
I want to trigger all of them, but I want B1 to be added to the build queue more than once.

For example, this is how I want my build queue to look like:
B1
B2
B3
B1

Is that possible?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by running your builds this way?  You will likely need to find a new approach, or create a new build B4 instead of running B1 twice.

Comment: Adding builds to the build queue in my company must be manually (too long to explain why), sometimes we wish to see the behaviour of B1 after B3 ends, regardless whether B1 is already on queue. Creating B4 which is a copy of B1 is not possible I'm afraid...

Comment: So if your builds are added to the build queue manually, why not just click 'Run' in sequence for B1 B2 B3 B1?  Not really understanding the question.

Comment: You can't add the same build more than once to the build queue

Comment: Which version of TeamCity are you using?  I tested with 8.1.2 and it lets you add a build to the queue multiple times.

Comment: 9.0.5 enterprise edition